# Linking to other pages in spring

Tags: xml, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

So, I have a home page, done with Spring. This home page has a link, that should lead to another page with a form. But that second page is not showing. Im sure I am doing plenty of things wrong, but be nice, please, Im learning about Spring MVC and I am a bit confused.

This is the code:

The root-context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

<!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->

    <bean name="newuserformcontroller" class="my.package.Controllers.NewUserFormController"/>
    <bean name="simpleUrlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="mappings">
        <props>
            <prop key="/newuserform">newuserformcontroller</prop>

        </props>

    </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

The web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

NewUserFormController:

```
package my.package.Controllers;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

public class NewUserFormController {

@RequestMapping (value = "/newuserform", method = RequestMethod.GET)

public String newuser(){

    return "newuserform";

}
}
```

The servlet-context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<annotation-driven />

<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />


</beans:bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.development.testing" />



</beans:beans>
```

The home.jsp:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page session="false" %>
<html>
<head>
<title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>
Hello world!  
</h1>

<P>  The time on the server is ${serverTime}. </P>
<p><a href="<c:url value="/newuserform" />" > New User </a> </p>

</body>
</html>
```

And the newuserform.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>New User Form</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

When I click on the link, I receive an Error 404. How could I do so the user receives the newuserform.jsp when clicking the link?

Thank you!

Comment: I deleted my previous comment by mistake. I saw you had upvoted it. Did the solution work for you?

Comment: I didnt upvoted, and didnt test it yet, im going to do it now

Comment: If you meant at the home.jsp, adding .jsp to /newuserform, it didn't work...404 error page.

Comment: Is your newuserform.jsp file located at '/WEB-INF/views/newuserform.jsp'?

Comment: Yes, it is. BTW, I solved it. I let /newuserform in the jsp, made the Controller implement the interface "Controller", and in the method HandleRequest, i returned the ModelAndView this way: return new ModelAndView("newuserform"); And now the page is shown properly. Thank for helping me Sudarshan :)

Comment: Great. You can use 'Controller' OR 'Component' annotation to indicate that a class is a controller. If you use @Controller and component-scan, you won't require to specify controller beans in xml.